# How to deserialize a JObject that brings the data as Item1 , Item2?

Tags: c#

I have `([FromBody] JObject jObject)` to my method.
The `jObject` brings the data like:

```
{{
  "Item1": {
    "AssocEmployee": { ... },
    "ID": 79
  },
  "Item2": null
}}
```

Inside the method i am trying something like this :

```
var empAssignment = new EmployeeAssignment();
//var empAssignment = jObject.ToObject<EmployeeAssignment>();
//empAssignment.ID = jObject.Value<JArray>("Item1").Values<int>("id").FirstOrDefault();
empAssignment.ID = jObject["id"].Value<int>();
empAssignment.AssocEmployee = jObject.ToObject<Employee>();
```

The Item2 that is null is not a problem.
Item1 and Item2 are coming from Tuple. The real names of classes are EmployeeAssignment and Position.

Comment: Your json is invalid.  Can you post the valid json pls?

Comment: I got valid json by using `var jObjectToString = jObject.ToString();` And now the `{{ ` became `{`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to fix your json, by removing an extra pair of {}, after this try this code

```
    var items =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Items>(json);

    var empAssignment =items.EmployeeAssignment;

     var assocEmployee= empAssignment.AssocEmployee;

    var empAssignmentId = empAssignment.ID;
```

classes

```
public class Items
{
    [JsonProperty("Item1")]
    public EmployeeAssignment EmployeeAssignment { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Item2")]
    public object Item2 { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeAssignment
{  
    [JsonProperty("AssocEmployee")]
    public AssocEmployee AssocEmployee { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("ID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
public class AssocEmployee
{
}
```

Comment: Item1 and Item2 are coming from Tuple. The real names of classes are EmployeeAssignment and Position.

Comment: @Christos Why  is it not included in the question? I asked you about the real json.